# Undefined method `resource_owner_id' for nil:NilClass Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, access-token, doorkeeper

I'm in the process of setting up [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) and [OAuth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) for one of my Rails Applications. My goal is to allow api access to a user depending on their access_token, so that only a user can see their 'user_show' json. So far I have my development and production applications set up and authorized on the 'oauth2/applications' route.

My '/config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb'

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use.
  # Currently supported options are :active_record, :mongoid2, :mongoid3,
  # :mongoid4, :mongo_mapper
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do
  # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
  # Example implementation:
    User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id]) || redirect_to('/')
  end
end
```

and my '/api/v1/user/controller.rb' looks as such:

```
class Api::V1::UserController < Api::ApiController
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  def index
    user = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
    respond_with User.all
  end
  def show
    user = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
    respond_with user
  end
end
```

I have tried to gain access to the OAuth Applications table to see what is being created but I cannot access it in the rails console.

Thanks in advance for the insight!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Doorkeeper doesn't find any token.

Make sure you're sending it, either from url with `?access_token=#{token}` or `?bearer_token=#{token}`, either giving this token in headers using Bearer Authorization.

You also need to have in mind that a token could be associated only to an app, without a resource owner. So `resource_owner_id` value could be `nil` even with a valid token. It depends on what grant flow you're using (client credential flow is not associated with a resource owner). See https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki#flows

For the OAuth tables, try with `Doorkeeper::AccessToken.all` in a rails console.

Hope this helped